# vcl combobox doesn't always show that it has focus

Tags: delphi

When I tab from another control to a combo box it shows the box with a dotted line around the text, but when I set the control to be active programmatically, it doesn't show the same focus indicator.

Is there a work-around for this behaviour?

I have Delphi XE6

---

MCVE

```
unit Unit27;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm27 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form27: TForm27;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm27.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.SetFocus;
end;

end.

object Form27: TForm27
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form27'
  ClientHeight = 90
  ClientWidth = 246
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Left = 16
    Top = 8
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'Edit1'
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 152
    Top = 8
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object ComboBox1: TComboBox
    Left = 16
    Top = 39
    Width = 145
    Height = 21
    Style = csDropDownList
    ItemIndex = 2
    TabOrder = 2
    Text = '2'
    Items.Strings = (
      '0'
      '1'
      '2'
      '3')
  end
end
```

[image]

Start the app and left-click on `Button1`, which calls

```
  ComboBox1.SetFocus;
```

Notice that **no focus rectangle is drawn**, but the combo has focus as the following shows:
Hit keyboard arrow up or arrow down. The combo item changes and now the focus rectangle becomes visible.
After the focus rectangle once is shown, it is also drawn on the combo after a mouse click on Button1. So to repeat the problem, restart the app.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: "when I set the control to be active programmatically" Exactly how are you doing this? Can we see your code please?

Comment: `ComboBox.SetFocus;`?

Comment: Focus rectangle is drawn if you use keyboard accelerators. That's how the operating system works.

Comment: Run notepad, file open, hit tab once, document type button has focus rectangle. Close the dialog, file open again, hit file type combo with the mouse, no focus rectangle is drawn.

Comment: @Johan I am setting focus by: ActiveControl := ComboBox. I also tried ComboBox.SetFocus

Comment: @Sertac Notepad example is useful, as is comment on keyboard accelerators.

Comment: Thanks @Tom for setting up the MCVE & thereby showing me what is required.

Comment: @Sertac Showing a focus rectangle on the relevant control when starting the form would be useful, especially when the task assigned to the first tab stop is already completed before the form is called and focus should move to the second tab stop. Is there a Perform(WM_??? command that will do the job?

Comment: @Graham - I'm not sure. Read about how the messages work [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050503-53/?p=35723).

Comment: @Sertac This will do the job: ComboBox.SetFocus; ComboBox.Perform(WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0); (In case someone complains about writing it here, I don't have enough points to post an answer.)

Comment: @Graham - Eating the `WM_UPDATEUISTATE` at the form level also works.

Comment: Graham You are welcome! I found your question interesting but noticed it was getting both down votes and close votes because of missing code, so I cooked up the sample to try to prevent the q to be closed. Luckily @Sertac took the time to answer. IMO his answer is the more correct one and should be marked by you as such (click the tick mark under the votes of his answer). Your answer works too, thanks for that, but is a kind of workaround.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for that. Perhaps my question was voted down simply because I didn't add the obvious code, "ComboBox.SetFocus" or ActiveControl := ComboBox.  I certainly have a lot to learn about how to ask good questions that actually get answers. I am certainly grateful for coming to a solution - I have tried all sorts of work-arounds before, none of which were satisfactory. Mine & Sertac's both work, but as you say, his is better - At least I can set up all the combo-boxes on the screen to act in this way with one command in form activate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design of the operating system, prevents clutter on the screen when a user is not using the keyboard. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061005-00/?p=29463/) is a thorough explanation of the reasons. And [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050503-53/?p=35723) is an explanation of how the mechanism works.

You can send a [`WM_UPDATEUISTATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change the state of a window (and its child windows as per the documentation).

```
ComboBox1.Perform(WM_UPDATEUISTATE, MakeWParam(UIS_CLEAR, UISF_HIDEFOCUS), 0);
```

Above will update the UI state of the combobox as if keyboard cues are required.

You don't have to send the message at focus switch time, you can send it at form creation for instance. You can also choose to send the message to the parent form, for all the controls to behave consistently, and can include `UISF_HIDEACCEL` in the high-word of WParam to also show accelerator characters underlined.

Note that users already can choose to display keyboard indicators at all times system-wise. In Windows 7, the setting is at "Control Panel", "Ease of Access Center", "Make the keyboard easier to use", "Make it easier to use keyboard shortcuts", "Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys".

Answer (score 2):

To make the focus rectangle appear on a combo box, when setting the focus programmatically, you can use the following code:

```
ComboBox.SetFocus; 
ComboBox.Perform(WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0);
```